# IR LED won't turn on, but white LED will in IR repeater circuit

Tags: led, infrared

I have this soundbar in front of my TV, and I need to stretch my arm to operate it with the remote, so I decided to make a IR repeater as a starting analog-only (no programmable MCU) electronics project.

[image: Schematic diagram exported from Falstad]

[Link to Falstad circuit](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?cct=$%201%200.000005%2010.20027730826997%2050%205%2050%0Ag%200%20288%200%20336%200%0AR%2032%20288%2032%20336%200%200%2040%203.3%200%200%200.5%0AS%2016%20224%2016%20288%200%201%20false%200%202%0At%20224%20224%20272%20224%200%201%20-0.6696471446522299%205.09999999701325e-9%20340%0AR%20272%20128%20320%20128%200%200%2040%203.3%200%200%200.5%0Ag%20272%20288%20272%20336%200%0Ar%20128%20224%20224%20224%200%2051000%0Ar%20272%20128%20272%20208%200%2051000%0Aw%20272%20208%20432%20208%203%0Ax%20445%20215%20517%20218%204%2024%20Output%0Ax%20-81%20251%20-28%20254%204%2024%20Input%0Ab%20-160%20-54%20725%20431%200%0Aw%2016%20224%20128%20224%203%0Aw%20272%20240%20272%20288%203%0A162%20672%20208%20592%20208%202%20default-led%201%200%200%200.02%0Ag%20368%20368%20400%20368%200%0Aw%20432%20208%20432%20304%203%0At%20432%20304%20528%20304%200%201%20-0.7914740797913957%200.6696471497522298%20340%0Aw%20528%20288%20592%20288%200%0Aw%20592%20288%20592%20208%203%0Ag%20528%20320%20528%20368%200%0AR%20672%20208%20672%20160%200%200%2040%203.3%200%200%200.5%0AI%2016%2032%20592%2032%200%200.5%205%0A!%20default%200%20V,%5CsG%20O%20IR%5CsReceiver%20%5C0%0A208%20-96%2032%20-80%2032%200%20default%200%0Ad%20608%2032%20656%2032%202%20default%0Ax%20-86%20-10%20-13%20-7%204%2014%20IR%5CsReceiver%0Ax%20282%20-8%20329%20-5%204%2014%20Inverter%0Ax%20607%20-7%20652%20-4%204%2014%20IR%5CsLED%0Ao%208%2064%200%204099%201.25%200.00009765625%200%202%208%203%0Ao%206%2064%200%204099%200.0000762939453125%200.00009765625%201%202%206%203%0A)

The input is a TL1838 IR receiver 3-pin package with active low.

If I put a white LED in, it works, the LED flashes; but if I swap the LED to an IR LED, it doesn't work. If I use my camera, I can see the remote, but not the IR LED on the board.

Any help, and comments on my first circuit appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It does not work because it is the wrong component for the circuit, or wrong circuit for the component.

The TL1838 is a IR receiver module that demodulates the 38 kHz carrier away and leaves you the signal without 38 kHz carrier.

So either re-encode the 38 kHz carrier before sending it to the IR LED, or get a module that does not demodulate the signal.

Comment: I didn't say the TV didn't turn on, I said the LED didn't flash, but thanks for skipping ahead, and I will let you know if the TV doesn't turn on...  Meanwhile, however, any idea why the LED isn't flashing?  The white LED does flash...  What's different between the IR LED and the white LED?

Comment: You have no current limiting resistor, is the IR LED even working anymore? It might already be broken. Also, is the IR LED connected the correct way around? Even if it did flash in the cell phone camera, it will lack modulation so the IR receiver module in the TV won't see the signal as it requires modulated signal, like the TL1838 does. Assume the TV has similar IR receiver.

Comment: Bad circuit.  This is not a repeater, it's a demodulator.  It'll show you the raw data, but it won't be able to transmit to the TV.

Comment: Justin: Why would I need a current limiting resistor?  Transistors are current control devices, my current is limited by the transistors...  Yes both LEDs are fine, and I can operate the IR LED on its own like a normal LED.

Comment: Kyle B: It's an LED flasher.  I want to know why the IR LED isn't flashing while the white one flashes.

Comment: @poorandunlucky you need a current limiting resistor in order not to break the IR LED. Transistors are current controlled devices. Collector current is set by beta times base current. But in real life no transistor has an exact beta value, and therefore no circuit that depends on beta value should be made. It is much simpler to use the transistor as simple inverting on/off switch, and just add the LED resistor like people normally do.